# Mismatch between skeleton and mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]

Why does this mismatch between skeleton and mesh occur? If I have align the mesh to the skeleton in *Object Mode*, when I switch to *Edit Mode*, the body falls to the ground, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you didn't applied the transformations.
In object mode select the body and the armature (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>   ) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and click on *Apply all Transforms*.

The problem was that the armature was in *Pose Mode*, so the pose was in the correct position, but the rest position was the one that appeared when you enter in *Edit Mode*.

The solution I found was first, remove any pose to be sure it won't affect you later. Click the armature and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Pose Mode*, or click here
[image: Pose mode]

Once in pose mode, use  <kbd>A</kbd> to select all bones, then use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> to reset any rotation, movement and scale made for the pose. It will look like this
[image: Pose]

To be sure, go to the right menu and click the button that looks like a stickman and click on *Rest position*.

[image: Rest mode]

After that, go back to object mode and select everything (body and armature) after that, press  <kbd>R</kbd>,  <kbd>X</kbd> and `-90` to rotate everything to the "normal" position, after that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and apply all transforms.

[image: Apply transform]

Then, click the armature and press  <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter to *Edit Mode* and select **only the head** of the big bone below the body.

[image: edit mode]

Press  <kbd>R,  <kbd>Z</kbd></kbd> and `-90` so the bone will be looking to the front

[image: Bone Front]

With that the model will be at the right position in *Object Mode*, *Edit Mode* and *Pose Mode*.

[image: Pose mode from rest]

Remember to change from *Rest Mode* to *Pose Mode* in the stickman menu when you want to change the pose of the character.

Comment: OOKKK maaann thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

My Blender version is 3.4.

[image]

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to open the *Mesh* menu.

[image]

[image]

After applying all transformations, follow the object mode and edit mode images respectively.

[image]

Comment: You're in edit mode. Change to object mode and then follow the steps I said.

Comment: Please don't add extra information as an answer. If you want to add more information to your question use the 'Edit' button below it it and add it directly into the editor. As @Kai says it's probably because the rotation hasn't been applied to the object and armature in Object mode.

Comment: I tried with different things in a new file and couldn't get the same problem you have, could you upload your blend file here? https://blend-exchange.com

And then edit the post with the link it shows you once uploaded

Comment: Added the solution (not sure if the page notify when someone edits the answer, so I will notify you with a comment) I hope it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your time!!